# fuse takes too long time to mount /root/.cache/doc and /root/.cache/gvfs when I run any file manager as root

Tags: root, ubuntu-20.04, fuse, nautilus, unmount

This is the case where I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop 64-bit freshly installed and that I execute the command "sudo nautilus":
Unmounting and then deleting these directories unfortunately does not solve my problem because they are recreated the next time the system is restarted.
Also on Ubuntu 20.10 these folders are mounted when I run the command "sudo nautilus" but the problem does not occur, so it must be some bug of 20.04, and I have to use that, which is the latest LTS.

This is the case where I installed nemo as a file manager:
I don't need nautilus but nemo and I also need to click "Open as Root" from the GUI. The problem is the same with "sudo nemo" too, so it doesn't depend on the file manager but on the fact that fuse for some reason takes too long time to mount those two directories.
How can I solve my problem?

EDIT:

The real problem is "xdg-desktop-portal" that if uninstalled, it solves the problem but this is a non-solution.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xdg-desktop-portal/+bug/1878081